# Converting multi dimensional array to one dimensional for codeigniter insert

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is what my array is looking

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
array (size=2)
  'key' => string 'PresentAddressDisrict' (length=21)
  'value' => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'key' => string 'ParmanentAddressDistrict' (length=24)
  'value' => string '2' (length=1)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'key' => string 'Board' (length=5)
  'value' => string '1' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'key' => string 'FieldChoice' (length=11)
  'value' => string '1' (length=1)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  'key' => string 'Gender' (length=6)
  'value' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Tried multiple solutions like:

1. Flattening the array-

```php
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
foreach($it as $v) {
    echo $v, " ";
}
```

2. using loops:

```
foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

but not getting the desired result and still finding the way.

the need is:

```
array('PresentAddressDisrict' => 1, 'ParmanentAddressDistrict' => 2, 'Board' => 1, 'FieldChoice' => 1, 'Gender' => 1)
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some slick way using array_map or another function, but I would approach this simply:

```
// create a new empty array to store values in
$insert = array();

// iterate over your array of arrays
foreach($my_array AS $values) {
    // at this point, $values is something like:
    // array('key' => 'Gender', 'value' => '1')
    $insert[$values['key']] = $values['value'];
}

var_dump($insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an array functions approach that cale_b mentioned.

```
$values = array_map( function( $item ) {
    return $item['value'];
}, $array );

$keys = array_map( function( $item ) {
    return $item['key'];
}, $array );

$array = array_combine( $keys, $values );
```

Comment: hello everyone, I heartly thank you all for answering, I applied cale_b answer it worked for me.